# Unzip and load keras model python google colab

Tags: python, keras, load, google-colaboratory, unzip

I'm trying to load and unzip a Keras model simulataneously in Google CoLab and have tried a few combinations, I need something like

```
my_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(unzip '../content/my_folder/my_model.zip')
```

but I get an invalid syntax error. How would I do this?

Comment: Yes this code is not valid, unzip is a shell command, you cannot use it like that in python.

Comment: How could I do this in CoLab on the command line? Or do I have to unzip and upload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash commands in Google Colab have to be preceded with `!`. The following line of code will unzip the `my_model.zip` to your current working directory, which is `/content` folder:

```
! unzip '../content/my_folder/my_model.zip'
```

After that you can use the filename of the unzipped model to load it:

```
my_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('filename')
```